# Question about finite G-sets

Tags: gr.group-theory, equivariant-homotopy

Let G be a finite group with subgroups H and K.  Then the set of not necessarily equivariant maps from G/H to G/K is itself a finite G-set under the conjugation action.  Is there a good description of it?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. What kind of 'good description' do you want / expect?

Comment: A reasonable description of a finite $G$-set is its decomposition into transitive $G$-sets? Still the question is quite broad (e.g., the case $H=K=1$, i.e. describing $G^G$ as $G$-set, is not clear-cut, at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

Even though the following gives only a minor generalisation, here's one perspective:

Given any two sets with an action of a given group (the sets and the group don't even need to be finite) there is an induced action on the set of maps:

$$G\times \mathrm{Set}(X,Y)\to \mathrm{Set}(X,Y)$$
$$(g, f)\mapsto (x\mapsto (g^{-1}).f(g.x))$$

The fixpoints of this action are then precisely the equivariant maps.